# WebAssembly. C++ строки

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly

Ребята, помогите, я обычный студент, которому нужно сдать курсач. У меня есть функция на C++, которая возвращает std::string. Как мне использовать эту функцию в js? Я делал по туториалу https://medium.com/devschacht/daniel-simmons-get-started-with-webassembly-using-only-14-lines-of-javascript-89960df71498 ,используя онлайн компилятор для компиляции c++ в wasm файл, и у меня получилось вызвать функцию, которая возвращает число. Но с функцией, которая возвращает string  у меня выводится ошибка

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: WebAssembly Instantiation: Imports argument must be present and must be an object
    at scripts.js:7
```

c++ код функции

```
#include "iostream"

std::string hello(){
    return "hello";
}
```

js код:

```
let squarer;
let hello;
function loadWebAssembly(fileName) {
 return fetch(fileName)
 .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
.then(buffer => WebAssembly.compile(buffer))
.then(module => {return new WebAssembly.Instance(module) });
};

 loadWebAssembly('squarer.wasm')
  .then(instance => {
  squarer = instance.exports._Z7squareri;
  console.log('Finished compiling! Ready when you are...');
}); 

loadWebAssembly('test.wasm')
  .then(instance => {
   hello = instance.exports._Z5hellov;
   console.log('Finished compiling! Ready when you are...');
});
```

Comment: Попробуйте собирать валидный С++ код

Comment: @VTT const char* hello() {
 return "Hello";
} //так сгодиться?

Comment: наверное сгодится...